# C++ struct reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++

Suppose there are two struct A and B. They have a common struct C.
I would like to know if it is safe to call reinterpret_cast to A or B to C.
if not, is there any way to do so without any performance impact?

```
struct C
{
    string m_c1;
    int32_t m_c2;
    double m_c3;
    string m_c4;
};

struct A
{
    C m_a1;
    string m_a2;
    int32_t m_a3;
};

struct B
{
    C m_b1;
    string m_b2;
    int32_t m_b3;
    double m_b4;
};
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
        A a;
        a.m_a1.m_c1="A";
        a.m_a1.m_c4="AA";

        B b;
        b.m_b1.m_c1="B";
        b.m_b1.m_c4="BB";

        C* pc = reinterpret_cast<C*>(&a);
        cout << pc->m_c1 << " " << pc->m_c4 << endl;

        pc = reinterpret_cast<C*>(&b);
        cout << pc->m_c1 << " " << pc->m_c4 << endl;

        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Even if it is safe today, can you guarantee that the structure of A and B will never change in the future? And if one of them does change, will whoever changes them know that the C struct *has* to be the first member?

Comment: Nothing in your example code indicates why you don't do `C *pc = &a.m_a1;`, which is entirely safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you inherit both A,B from C and then use `static_cast` instead? Should be safer/cleaner.

Indeed in your case, you shouldnt need a cast at all, you should be able to assign A or B ptrs to a `C*`

Comment: It is seldom a good idea to inherit from a class just for the sake of convenience. Sooner or later this will lead to problems.

Comment: @Gorpik It depends on the meaning of A,B,C but it does sound like inheritance is a fair interpretation of their relationship. plus the choice is made for cleaner,safer code, not more convenient code.

Comment: We have no idea of their relationship because we don't know what are those structs modelling. We don't even know why is OP trying to use a cast there. Public inheritance should model an IS-A relationship; otherwise, someone will sometime try to use an A where a C is needed and have their code behave nonsensically.

Comment: The way this particular example is written strongly, strongly suggests is-a, and therefore inheritance, relationships. Further, if inheritance is used, along with `static_cast`, it avoids the whole what-if-it-has-`virtual`-methods case I mentioned in the comment on icepack's answer, because `static_cast` will take care of doing the right thing.

Comment: Agree. Inheritance is the way to go. I agree with Gorpik that public inheritance should model an IS-A relationship, but private inheritance is a perfectly valid way to express IS-IMPLEMENTED-AS. The code from the question doesn't express which of the two applies.

Comment: I agree. This seems to be written in a C-style inheritance way. Also, obviously the OP is trying to use both A and B as a C here, which means A must be a C for that to make any sense at all.

Answer (score 3):

As Mike DeSimone points out the `string` class is not guaranteed to be a `standard-layout` class, and thus the class `C` is not `standard-layout`, which means that you have no guarantees of the memory layout at all. So it is **not safe**. Only if you change the string to a `(const) char*` it will be guaranteed to be safe.

Even then it will only be safe as long as the layout of the classes stays the same (you cannot change the order of members or change the access specifier on them), and the classes stays without any vtables, this is "safe" in such a way that the compiler will generate code that display the behavior you would like.

This is how ever two guarantees that a software developer seldom is able to give. Also the code is hard to understand written like this. Another developer (or the same developer a month later) might ignore the this code (or simply don't understand it), and do the changes needed, and suddenly the code is broken and you got some hard to catch errors on your hand.

`A` and `B` are classes that give access to a `C` (or some members of `C`). More readable and thus more safe solutions are:

- Create an accessor for both `A` and `B`, this would probably be inlined and incur no performance penalty.
- If there is any reason for inheritance use simple inheritance. Either `A` and `B` *is-a* `ClassThatHasAC` or `A` and `B` *is-a* `C` As long as there are no virtual functions you would probably not see any performance issues here either. In both cases an accessor would provide you benefits probably without any performance cost.

Create some simple and readable code at first, and measure performance. **Onli if this C access is costing you too much, optimize.** But if your optimization boils down to the reinterpret cast trick make sure that there are plenty of warning signs around to make sure that no one steps on this booby trap.